What are the 8 blue circles on the dorsal side of the Defiant on DS9?
What are the 8 blue circles on the dorsal side of the Defiant in Star Trek: DS9?


Don't know about you, but I'm having trouble finding a picture with them in (or remembering them). Are you able to post one for us and cite the particular episode?

@JiminyCricket. - They're more prominent on the eaglemoss plastic model. I have added a photo for emphasis.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

lol. If you like them, you can buy your own; https://www.shapeways.com/product/8MMGWCWMG/defiant-1-420-scale-amt-plasma-vents

Out of universe? Greebles.

Panzer III idler wheels

Well, since their placement is out of sight they must be some functioning component of the vessel and not insignia or distinction markings which would be on clearly visible surfaces like it's name is shown.

(continuing) Though at this future time setting I'd suppose such information would be broadcast as boasting messages on all hailing channels in idle time, rather than 'painted' on the side like the ancient mariners.

The plan view provided in (Star Trek: The Official Starships Collection #9) indicates that these are plasma vents.


I've taken the liberty of upgrading your answer with a better picture and a link to the source. You can read the magazine in full here; https://archive.org/details/09-issue-defiant/page/n9/mode/2up?view=theater

The wonderfully illustrated Ships of the Line Calendar 2023 indicates that these are 'energizers', port and starboard.


Interestingly, the Strategic Designs USS Defiant - External Blueprints and Internal Deck Plans lists these as 'Warp Plasma Cooling / Vent Toroids'

And the (2004) Jackill's Data Sheets - Defiant Class - Escort Cruiser list these as 'plasma vents (8)'

